# Wampserver: long "waiting" delay for php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I've read many posts on many fora about boosting Wampserver with php/mysql and tried many tips on many files (on windows hosts file, http.conf, php.ini, my.ini...) but none succeeded in speeding up my local tests.
Using Firebug to analyse HTTP requests (hovering the timeline in the "net panel), I note that every request is mainly slowed down by the "waiting" state, e.g.

```
Blocking 0ms | 1ms
DNS lookup +1ms | 0 ms
Connecting +1ms | 0ms
Sending +1ms | 0ms
Waiting +1ms | 8.85s
Receiving +8.85s | 62ms
```

Which component can be responsible for this dramatically long "waiting" state ?
If I get some clue, I'd know where to focus my attention.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly open up http.conf file and add the following lines at the bottom of the page,

Include "d:/wamp/alias/*"

AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none

Let me know if this fixed for you?

Comment: Well... first line was already there but both the last ones were commented out. I gain 50% in speed right now. Many thanks for your help Pundit !

Comment: My pleasure, if I can come across new experiences I'll keep updated in commets. Thanks alot!